# DiffEq: When to sub init. cond. to determine +C

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

So, in this one, once I got to y^2 = .... (Bottom left)
I subbed right there, and got 1 solution.

But, can't you solve for y = +-sqrt(...) and get 2 solutions?
Is there an accepted method?

[image]

Comment: It's the + version because you pass through $(-1,1)$.  If your condition were $(-1,-1)$ then it would be the - version.

Comment: the problem is here $(-8)^{2/3}$ it is one real number and two complex numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the form of your differential equation, $${dy\over dx}={x^2\over y\,\root 3 \of {9x^3+1}},$$ we see that the ${dy\over dx}$ is undefined when $y=0$ or $9x^3+1=0\implies x=(-1/9)^{1/3}$. These two values partition the plane into four regions. Since your initial condition is $x=-1,\,y=1$, you want the solution defined in the region with $y>0$, so you take the *positive* square root, as you did.

Comment: 4 regions b/c  Y can not equal 0, and X can not equal (−1/9)1/3.  Ok, so 2 dashed lines, if you will.  The the solution (a function) can't exist on multiple regions, b/c it would have to cross the boundries

Comment: @JackOfAll Yes.